# Read method returning twice the number of samples actually present

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, sampling

I have the following code to read the samples of an audio file into a byte array.

```
int signal_read = signal.Read(signal_sample, 0, signal_length);
MessageBox.Show(signal_read + "");
```

where `signal` is an object of `WaveFileReader`class.

MessageBox.Show always shows twice the actual number of samples got from the software **Audacity**.

Does `read` method not return the number of samples read from audio?

Comment: Number of bytes vs. number of samples? One channel or two channels?

Comment: And what is `signal` here?

Comment: WaveFileReader signal = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\signal.wav")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it returns the number of bytes read.

So for a 16-bit PCM wav, it will give you twice the amount of samples. If it's a stereo 16-bit, you'll get four times as much.

Instead of reading the bytes, you probably want to use the overload that fills a `float[][]` array. For example, for a single-channel audio:

```
var array = new float[][] { new float[sampleCount] };

var actualSamples = signal.Read(array, sampleCount);
```

Comment: Yes! My audio is 16-bit 1 channel! Thank you so much!
So, if I were to find the RMS, I am to divide the numerator by ((signal_length/2)) ?

Comment: @bboyetricks Not exactly. You also need to make sure you're not calculating each byte separately - they come in pairs, together making a single `short` value. Try using the `float[][]` overload as I've outlined in the answer now. Oh, and note that it only works for 16-bit wavs, but that should be fine for you :)

Comment: If I add adjacent 2 sample values stored in byte array at a time and keep storing them in a short array, wont it be the same?

Comment: @bboyetricks If you add them properly, yeah (e.g. use `BitConverter.ToInt16`). Don't forget to divide by `32768f`, though.

Comment: you mean: samples_short[0] = (samples_byte[0] + samples_byte[1])/32768?

Comment: @bboyetricks The values aren't *added*, they form a `short`. The total range isn't `0 - 510`, it's `-32767 - 32768`. Really, just stick to the `float[][]` overload, it will give you values from -1 to 1, it's far more useful anyway.

Comment: also, Read method requires array to be as byte type instead float..there are no overload methods for Read

Comment: @bboyetricks Hmm, I was looking at a modified version. In that case, you can get the data like `for (var i = 0; i < byteCount / 2; i++) floatArray[i] = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(byteArray[i * 2]) / 32768f;`. Or, if you don't need to *store* the samples, you can just do your calculations directly on this.

Comment: errors,,,1) BitConverter.ToInt16 takes 2 parameter (2) First is a byte array and second is startIndex..This function returns a 16-bit signed integer converted from two bytes at a specified position in a byte array

Comment: @bboyetricks Ah, of course, you pass `byteArray` as the first argument and `i * 2` as the second. I was in a bit of a rush :)

Comment: if i am to calculate the RMS value of my audio now, is this code correct:  for(i=0; i<noise_arr.Length; i++)
 {
                noise_arr[i] = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(noise_sample, i * 2) / 32768f;
                sum += (noise_arr[i] * noise_arr[i]);
            }

            float rms_noise = (float)Math.Sqrt((sum / noise_arr.Length));

Comment: Before writing the float array I will have to re-convert it to byte so that WaveFileWriter can write it to the destination...how do I do that?

Comment: @bboyetricks Looks fine to me, except that you want to force `float` division - `(float)Math.Sqrt(((float)sum / (float)noise_arr.Length))`. Oh, and you shouldn't work with `noise_arr.Length` - instead, you need to use the return value of `WaveFileReader.Read`, divided by two. If there's less samples than you requested, you'll get bogus data in the rest of the array. As for the `WaveFileWriter`, what are you actually trying to save? Are you renormalizing the sound file, correcting gain or something like that?

Comment: I changed that division statement..it didnt make any diff though...and my noise_arr is defined this: `noise_read = noise.Read(noise_sample, 0, noise_length) / 2; noise_arr = new float[noise_read]` so this way I am making my array of that (samples read /2) size only :) and my wavefilewriter I have implemented this way: 
`using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"E:\aw4.wav", noise.WaveFormat))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++)
                    writer.WriteSample(noise_arr[i]);
            }`

Comment: @bboyetricks And what's the problem with that? That should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I found this method after I posted this query in comment :P Thank you